# Generating the digits in a base system by repeated multiplication of a number

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, digits

The first 15 terms of the sequence `{a_i} = 2^i` are 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768. All of the digits in base-10, i.e. {0, 1, 2, ..., 9}, each appear in at least one of these terms, and 32768 is the first term to contain the digit 7.

Define the *digital potency* (this is a term I came up with, I am unaware if there is a proper term for this) of *n* in base-10 to be the minimum value of *x* such that the digits {0, 1, 2, ..., 9} each appear in at least one of *n*, *n^2*, *n^3*, ..., *n^x*.

Thus, from the above example, the digital potency of 2 in base-10 is 15.

More generally, define the digital potency of *n* in base-*b* to be the minimum value of *x* such that the digits {0, 1, 2, ..., b-1} each appear in at least one of the base-*b* representations of *n*, *n^2*, *n^3*, ..., *n^x*.

**Observation 1:** For any numeral system base-*b*, we can construct a number with digital potency of 1 by simply concatenating the digits {0, 1, 2, ..., b-1}.

**Observation 2:** If *n* is a perfect power of *b*, then the digital potency of *n* in base-*b* is undefined or 'infinite' (i.e., there exists a digit in {0, 1, 2, ..., b-1} that never appears in any of the terms of the sequence `{a_i} = m^i`). I believe that this is actually true so long as *n* is a rational power of *b*.

Has this concept been studied before? I wrote some Python code to calculate the digital potency of various numbers in various bases, and it seems to have some interesting behavior. For instance, if you fix *n* and calculate the digital potency for various choices of *b*, the values seem rather unpredictable. Similarly, if you fix *b* and calculate the digital potency for various choices of *n*, the values also seem unpredictable.

Some specific questions I have:

- Is there an easy way to calculate or at least approximate digital potency without explicitly calculating the powers of a number?
- Is there a non-trivial example of a number and a base system where digital potency is undefined?

Comment: For the second question, no. For any number $n$ and base $b$ with $log_b(n)$ irrational, $klog_b(n)$ for $k\geq1$ obeys the Weyl equidistribution law, hence all possible digits in $0...b-1$ occur as first digits.

Comment: @Bullet, I'd say zero *never* occurs as first digit.

Comment: A distantly related and, I believe, unsolved problem is to show that for all sufficiently large $n$ there is a zero somewhere in the decimal representation of $2^n$. See, e.g., http://oeis.org/A238938

Comment: @GerryMyerson But zero could appear as _second_ digit. The Weyl equidistribution law still applies.

Comment: @Bullet, sure, and if you had written, all possible digits in $0,\dots,b-1$ occur as second digits, I would have had no objection.